# How to add plots on a small multiple visualization using d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

Current situation: I already have a small multiple visualization for my data. What it represents is the stress intensity over time for six different days. It plots the graphs correctly. Now I wanted to add dots on the existing graph if the person smoked at that time. I am reading a csv file which consists of date, time, stress level and whether the person smoked or not (so 1 if they did and -1 if they didn't). I am using d3 v4.

[image]

This is what I am currently getting but the red dots are obviously in the wrong spot because they are showing up places I don't even have data. 
What I wanted was for the red dots to be on the graph and represent the times the user smoked.

Code:

```
<script>

    var margin = {top: 8, right: 10, bottom: 2, left: 10},
            width = 1160 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");

    var x = d3.scaleTime()
            .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
            .range([height, 0]);

    var area = d3.area()
            .x(function (d) {
                return x(d.time);
            })
            .y0(height)
            .y1(function (d) {
                return y(d.stress);
            });

    var line = d3.line()
            .x(function (d) {
                return x(d.time);
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return y(d.stress);
            });

    d3.csv("6000smokedData3.csv", type, function (error, data) {

        // Nest data by date.
        var dates = d3.nest()
                .key(function (d) {
                    return d.date;
                })
                .entries(data);

        // Compute the maximum stress per date, needed for the y-domain.
        dates.forEach(function (s) {
            s.maxPrice = d3.max(s.values, function (d) {
                return d.stress;
            });
        });

        // Compute the minimum and maximum time across dates.
        // We assume values are sorted by time.
        x.domain([
            d3.min(dates, function (s) {
                return s.values[0].time;
            }),
            d3.max(dates, function (s) {
                return s.values[s.values.length - 1].time;
            })
        ]);

        // Add an SVG element for each date, with the desired dimensions and margin.
        var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                .data(dates)
                .enter().append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        //Add the scatterplot
        svg.selectAll("dot")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("circle")
                .attr("r", 4)
                .style("fill", function (d) {
                    return "red";
                })
                .attr("cx", function (d) {
                    if (d.smoked == 1) {
                        return x(d.time);
                    }
                })
                .attr("cy", function (d) {
                    if (d.smoked == 1) {
                        return y(d.stress);
                    }
                });

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
                .call(d3.axisLeft(y));

        // Add the area path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
        svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "area")
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]);
                    return area(d.values);
                });

        // Add the line path elements. Note: the y-domain is set per element.
        svg.append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    y.domain([0, d.maxPrice]);
                    return line(d.values);
                });

        // Add a small label for the date name.
        svg.append("text")
                .attr("x", width - 6)
                .attr("y", height - 6)
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text(function (d) {
                    return d.key;
                });
    });

    function type(d) {
        d.stress = +d.stress;
        d.time = parseDate(d.time);
        d.smoked = +d.smoked;
        return d;
    }

</script>
```

Few lines of csv file:

`date,time,stress,smoked
2014-08-04,11:24:28,0.026191,-1
2014-08-04,11:24:29,0.026183,-1
2014-08-04,11:24:30,0.031845,-1
2014-08-04,11:24:31,0.01235,-1`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're drawing the dots before you set the y scale for each element. I usually like to make [small multiples](https://bl.ocks.org/1wheel/fa160fe77111ef4165d6) inside of an `each` loop to avoid tricky things like. It looks like the y axis is also off - they should be different on each plot.